# Is there a good information source for the (dis)advantages of various metrics for diversity?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I am interested in applying one of the many indices used to measure heterogeneity and diversity in a particular context.

For instance, I could choose between alpha, beta, gamma or zeta diversity; or I could try gini-simpson, inverse simpson, the generalized entropy index, etc.

The problem is there are so many of them that I feel implementing each one by one is probably not the most efficient approach. Rather, I'd like to learn (quickly, if possible) what each is best at, then implement a few that are likely to be best.

As such, what I'd like to have is a review article of the advantages and disadvantages of each so I can get an intuitive understanding, then perhaps implement the most promising ones.

For context, the problem I want to solve is this:

There is a gene that gets re-arranged to form a fusion product that drives cancer. There are many cases in which, in only one patient, this rearrangement will occur more than once, presumably forming de novo in different cells. I want to measure the diversity of the number of distinct types of this fusion gene that form, and quantify that as a metric of heterogeneity.

Any and all help greatly appreciated, and thank you for reading.

Comment: Update, so far, I found this, which is not bad. https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/veg_measure/modules/lessons/module%209(composition&diversity)/9_3_Estimating%20Biodiversity.htm   Ideally, I'd find something geared towards genomics and a bit more rigorous.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found an answer that has everything I need. It is [here][1]:

Diversity and Evenness: A Unifying Notation and Its Consequences
March 1973Ecology 54(2):427-432 Follow journal
DOI: 10.2307/1934352
Mark Oliver Hill

I will close the question once enough time has elapsed for me to do so, and thank you.
[1]: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1934352

Comment: Please edit your question to include this non-answer.